# How to update a non time dependent variable each time step of scipy.odeint

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I'm trying to solve the problem of fluid flowing out of a tank; utilizing the continuity and energy conservation equations. Initially, the tank has some pressure and some enthalpy which are used in a 2D lookup table to get other fluid properties. As the fluid leaves the tank, the pressure and enthalpy change; thus, leading to my issue. Enthalpy is solved for by the energy equation thus when using odeint and giving the initial condition, enthalpy will update every time-step. The issue lies with pressure, pressure is solved for by solving the continuity equation and then using a correlation where pressure is a function of density. The question is how do you get a non time-dependent variable like pressure to be updated every time step of odeint.

I've looked through a lot on here to find something similar but a lot of what I've seen is a time-dependent variable changing. So if time < 2, then x = 0 .. if time >= 2, then x = 2. I was trying to figure out a way to rearrange the equations to make it a function of time but it's not a direct function of time like y(t) = m*t + b. I don't know maybe I'm overthinking the heck out of this.

```py
# Model of Tank:

def model(IC,time,terms,terms2):
    #   Initial Conditions:
    #   IC[0] = Initial Tank Mass
    #   IC[1] = Initial Percent Quality of Vapor in Tank
    #   IC[2] = Initial Pressure for PI Controller
    #   IC[3] = Initial Enthalpy

    #   System of Equations:
    sysdot = [[],[],[],[]]

    #   Continuity Equation:
    # dMdt = mdot_in - mdot_out(pump) - mdot_out(vapor bleed off)
    mdot_in = 0
    mdot_outVapor = terms[2]
    M_total = IC[0]
    sysdot[0] = mdot_in - mdot_outVapor - terms[1]

    #   Transfer Function Equation:
    # NOTE: I was given a Simulink model to write in python, not sure on the use 
    # of the Transfer Function but I need it in the system of equations to solve for 
    # the percent quality which includes the quality lookup tables.
    # dXdt = (X_percent - X)/tau **Note: X = X(h,P,file)
    tau = .125
    if time == 0:
        # Here is where I define the initial Pressure
        P_in = 50e3
        X_percent = IC[1]
        X = X2D(IC[3],P_in,terms[5]) # The terms[5] here is the file location of the lookup table
        sysdot[1] = (X_percent - X)/tau
        density = (M_total*X_percent)/(terms[3] - (M_total*(1 - X_percent))/terms[0])
        P_in = P_sat_vap(density) # Solve for my new pressure
    else:
        X_percent = IC[1]
        X = X2D(IC[3],P_in,terms[5]) # <--- Problem child
        sysdot[1] = (X_percent - X)/tau
        density = (M_total*X_percent)/(terms[3] - (M_total*(1 - X_percent))/terms[0])
        P_in = P_sat_vap(density)

    # … more code …

    return sysdot
```

Currently, how the code is set up an error occurs saying P_in is not defined first. Even though at time x = 0, I have it calculating a new P_in for the future time steps. Do I need to use SciPy's ode function, and put everything in a loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Though the code is well commented, it maybe overwhelming for someone who looks at it for the first time. However, this link may help with your problem: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14765/scipy-integrate-odeint-how-can-odeint-access-a-parameter-set-that-is-evolving-i

Comment: Thank you @amanb! I read this post before posting my question. I wasn't sure how similar it was but after re-reading it I can see the similarities. In the post you sent, it talked about querying an update; do you have any suggestions on how one may go about that or is it impossible to do as later comments suggest in that post?

Comment: Do you initialize time to 0? What does P_sat_vap do?

Comment: @Patol75, Yes. Time is: time = np.arrange(0,30,0.01). P_sat_vap is a forth-order polynomial curve fit correlation that relates density to pressure.

Comment: Would you mind providing the full code and the Traceback from Python? It is hard to just guess here.

Answer (score 0):

`P_in` might only be defined in the scope of the `model` function, but I think you have a deeper issue.

`P_in` seems to be a nonlinear function that you need to estimate from the state variables, which confusingly seem to be also coded as `IC` here.  I'd recommend *not* trying to save the old state of `P_in` from the internal ode solution as sometimes the integrator can try multiple steps before it accepts one, and this method will cause weird behavior whereby it is using a `P_in` from an unacceptable step attempt.

Instead, let `P_in` only depend on the current state values and use a stiff solver.